# Difference between passing an integer and a string parameter in jQuery

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have function in which I create a div containing an `onclick` function, where I pass 2 variables. One is an `int` and the another one is a `string`. It's accepting the `int` and not the `string`.

```
  var html ="";
  var intC = 0;
  var flightBI="";
  var mileage=0;
  flightBI = $(this).find("FLIGHT").text();

 fnCreateDiv(){
 html+="<div class='ui-grid-a' id='Details" + intC +"'            onclick='fnConfirm("+intC+","+mileage+");' >";
 html+="</div>"
 }

 fnConfirm(intc,mileage){
 alert(intc);
 alert(mileage);
 }
```

I am getting an alert for both `intc` and `mileage`, since both are integers.  If in the same case I pass the flight, I am not getting a value.  This is what we usually do with JavaScript but is it different in jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

intC and mileage are both initialized to 0 (int) so they both alert the same value.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bN4JJ/1/) with the fix

Comment: Sorry for responding you late.....Thanks! Your Solution helped me to fix the problem of integer and string. I am still learning things in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I too tried to find a solution for my question and found the escape sequence \" helped me out.

onclick='fnConfirm("+intC+","+flightBI+")

replaced as

onclick='fnConfirm("+intC+",\""+mileage+"\")

since i am adding html itself as a string.